# How to set a colormap in interactive plot animations in python

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib, scatter-plot

The code below creates an animation of 600k points by scatter plotting 30k of them per frame. The animation works flawlessly, except for the fact that I don't know how to include my colormap (Heatintensity) in the animation. The Xs and Ys are changing but the color of the points is just blue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Heatintensity=workdata[0:600000] #Values controlling scatter colormap
Xs=xCoord[0:600000]
Ys=yCoord[0:600000]

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(Xs, Ys, c=Heatintensity, cmap=cm.jet, s=5)

plt.draw()
for i in range(20):
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[Xs[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000],\
                        Ys[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000]])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for random data that I created. Are you sure that whatever is in ``Heatintensity`` is of the right ``dtype`` and of different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the colors, you need to use

```
sc.set_array(Heatintensity[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000])
```

in addition to changing the offsets.

In order for the colors to represent the same numerical values for each animation step, the scatter must be normalized to all data,

```
norm = plt.Normalize(Heatintensity.min(), Heatintensity.max())
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Heatintensity=np.random.rand(600000) #Values controlling scatter colormap
Xs=np.random.rand(600000)
Ys=np.random.rand(600000)

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

norm = plt.Normalize(Heatintensity.min(), Heatintensity.max())
sc = ax.scatter(Xs, Ys, c=Heatintensity, s=5, cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=norm)

plt.draw()
for i in range(20):
    # set coordinates
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[Xs[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000],\
                        Ys[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000]])
    # set colors
    sc.set_array(Heatintensity[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000])
    # draw and make pause
    plt.pause(0.1)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

The same can be achieved using a `FuncAnimation`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

Heatintensity=np.random.rand(600000) #Values controlling scatter colormap
Xs=np.random.rand(600000)
Ys=np.random.rand(600000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

norm = plt.Normalize(Heatintensity.min(), Heatintensity.max())
sc = ax.scatter(Xs, Ys, c=Heatintensity, s=5, cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=norm)


def update(i):
    # set coordinates
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[Xs[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000],\
                        Ys[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000]])
    # set colors
    sc.set_array(Heatintensity[(i*30000):(i*30000)+30000])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(20), interval=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow thank you for going above and beyond with the extra info about FuncAnimation